# Cannot access internet through ethernet on freshly installed Ubuntu

Tags: internet, dns, ethernet, ping

I just installed ubuntu 18.04 and cannot get access through internet through ethernet cable

Here are the command I already tried to get an idea about the problem. Is enp0s25 the name of the ethernet connection

```
~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:a9:05:f0:05:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

~$ ping -c3 www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

I'm trying to solve the problem by looking at the page [to manually set network settings](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-manual.html.en). There, I'm ask to type:

- IP Address
- Gateway
- Netmask

Are the 3 information in the output provided and if yes what are they exactly? Is my IP Address 127.0.0.1?, What is my Gateway and Netmask?

**EDIT 1**

Here is the output of the following commands

```
~$ sudo ethtool eth0
sudo: ethtool: command not found
~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 02
       serial: 18:a9:05:f0:05:13
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.4-3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:31 memory:f0000000-f001ffff memory:f0025000-f0025fff ioport:2100(size=32)
```

**EDIT 2**

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
cat: /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml: No such file or directory
$ ls /etc/netplan/
01-network-manager-all.yaml
$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Yes, enp0s25 is the name of your ethernet connection. Looks like it's not configured or not configured for DHCP.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @rsr911. Do you have any idea about what should I try as a next step?

Comment: This should help: https://netplan.io/examples/

Comment: Hi, 127.0.01 is the IPv4 loopback interface address. It's not an actual IP address. It looks like there is not IP address assigned to your network interface which is `enp0s25`, as it is mentioned above. Please, [edit] the question and provide the output of the command `cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` if this file exists, or if it doesn't exist provide the output of `ls /etc/netplan/`. Here is an reference with some clues: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: many thanks @pa4080. I provided the output in edit 2

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a link (`enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>`) so assuming there is a dhcp server configured on your network you could try to manually request an ip address:

```
sudo dhclient enp0s25
```

Did you get an IP now?

```
ip a
```

If this didn't help it could be that something went wrong with the negotiation of your link speed and duplex. What is the output of:

```
sudo ethtool eth0
```

What kind of network card do you have?

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @simon. Unfortunately the command did not change anything

Comment: thanks again @simon . I provided the output of the commands that you suggested in edit 1

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following steps:

1st create a backup copy of the original configuration file.

```bsh
sudo cp /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml{,.bak}
```

Then modify the file. If there is DHCP server that automatically assigning IP addresses and other communication parameters to devices connected to the network - in most cases the home routers does this by default - change the configuration to this:

```bsh
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
```

Note Netplain supports Netplan supports both networkd and NetworkManager as backends. In this case we choose `networkd`. If there is not available DHCP server, or you want to assign a static IP address, change the configuration to this:

```bsh
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      addresses: [192.168.1.101/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
```

Where:

- `192.168.1.101` will be the IP address of the device and it depends on your LAN configuration.
- `192.168.1.1` is the IP address of your router and it also depends on your LAN configuration.
- `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` are the Google's NameServers, here we using them as backup.

Finally restart `networkd.service` to take effect:

```bsh
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service
```

Then check it's status:

```bsh
sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd.service
```

References:

- **https://netplan.io/examples/#using-network-manager-as-a-renderer**
- https://serverspace.io/support/help/how-to-restart-network-in-ubuntu
- https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @pa4080. Actually my IP adress had to be registered in the network of my workplace. That was the problem